# Работа с foreign key в сущностях EF Code Frist

Tags: asp.net, c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, .net

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть сущности, допустим Product и Category.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string Name {get;set}
    public int? ParentCategoryId {get;set}
    public virtual Category Category {get;set}
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
public class Product 
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string Name {get;set}
    public int? CategoryId {get;set}
    public virtual Category Category {get;set}
}
```

На каждую сущность есть свой репозиторий, который соответственно используют разные экземпляры контекcта EF.

Задача следующая: в базе могут находиться продукты которые не принадлежат ни одной категории(т.к. FK - Allow Null), потом я могу отметить список продуктов и внести изменения привязав коллекцию продуктов к категории...

```
//где-то расположен код...
List<Products> products =
    new EfProductRepository().GetНужныеПродукты(); //Формальность 
category.Products.Add(products); //category - уже существующая категория
new EfCategoryRepository().Save(category);
```

метод Save(...) в репозитории категорий...

```
public void Save(Category category) //Id этой категории сейчас не 0
{
    if (category.Id == 0)
    {
        context.Categories.Add(category);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Получается следующее: Ef дублирует все продукты из списка и стоит на них foreign key, а они уже были выбраны из базы ранее.

Если делать наоборот: присваивать каждому продукту экземпляр категории то тогда размножаются категории..

`Entry<...>(...).State = .Modified` тоже не помогает. Знаю что проблема из-за того что используются разные экземпляры контекста EF. Как решить данную проблему?

*Примечание*

- без варианта использования синглтона для контекста
- DI-контейнер не используется

Comment: А если попробовать элементы одного контекста задетачить (State = EntityState.Detach)?

Comment: @NekoSin4eG, пробовал - результат тот же

Comment: А если сделать банально в лоб, хоть и не совсем корректно. Сделать контекст глобальным для двух методов. Но да, проще и правильнее синглтон сделать.

Comment: @NekoSin4eG, контексты находятся в разных репозиториях...
Точно знаю, что есть решение, знакомый программер говорил, что когда-то справлялся с этим, но не помнит как и то наверно был не EF 6, а более ранняя версия...

Comment: Хм. А почему в разных репозиториях? Это принципиально? Не являются ли у вас случайно контексты долгоживущими?

Comment: @VladD, Не контексты разные, а экземпляры контекстов. В EfProductRepository и EfCategoryRepository. Контексты не долгоживущие.
Если делаю не так
category.Products.Add(products); //category - уже существующая категория

а так...

foreach(var product in products)
{
    product.CategoryId = category.Id
}
то все Ок

Comment: @devEugene: Ну да, а почему разные экземпляры контекстов? То есть, почему свой репозиторий? Почему бы не свести в один?

Comment: @VladD, Если бы как тут в примере было 2 сущности, я бы может и не делал несколько репозиториев, сделал универсальный UnitOfWork. А так нужен Repository Pattern и применение DI.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй устанавливать в значение EntityState.Unchanged для сущностей которые уже существуют и дублируются при сохранение.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) 
{ 
    context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Unchanged; 

    // Do some more work...  

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Это в принципе то же самое, что вызывать Attach для объекта

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) 
{ 
    context.Categories.Attach(category); 

    // Do some more work...  

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```